# Override CMFCTabCtrl

Tags: visual-c++

I have created an derivated class from `CMFCTabCtrl` to have access to the `ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message.
But it doesn't work, I think in `CMainFrm`  I have somewhere to replace the origional class with my derivated class. But I can not find no place where the original `CMFCTabCtrl` class is called. So I guess that maybe happens inside another class.
By the way, `EnableMDITabbedGroups` is enabled.

Comment: Short answer is that `CMDIClientAreaWnd` has `CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTab;` as a member, so you cannot change that to a different class/type short of replacing `CMDIClientAreaWnd` entirely. But depending on what you need to do about `ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN` there may be other ways.

Comment: @dxiv, I want to open a menu to change the document view.

Comment: Don't know that's possible to hook that into right-click without some major hacking into `CMDIClientAreaWnd::CreateTabGroup` (which *is* virtual, so overridable, even if not documented). For one thing, there may be more than one CMFCTabCtrl controls that you would need to replace.

Comment: Sounds complicated!